# blocking api redirect with requests in python 3.4

Tags: python, json

I  am creating a python program that uses an online thesaurus and returns synonyms.  Unfortunately sometimes it will take a word that is spelled wrong, and redirect to a page for a word that is close to it, which is sometimes problematic.  How can I stop it from redirecting?  I would appreciate any advice.  This is the code that applies:

```
def get_synonym(the_word):
    #return a dictionary of the thesaurus results of the word
    theurl = (the api key for the thesaurus)
    new_word = the_word + "/json"
    theurl = theurl + new_word
    r = requests.get(theurl)    
    thewords = r.text   #all the text for the results
    from json import loads
    thewords = json.loads(thewords) #make a dictionary of terms
    return thewords #return dictionary of synonyms for the_word
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`allow_redirects=False`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) keyword argument:

```
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)
```

By default, requests follows redirects on all methods except `HEAD`.